What linear map are the Pauli spin matrices a representation of?
Let $T:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear map and let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B} $ be ordered bases for two $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces $V$ and $W$.
Then one can denote the matrix representation of $T$ with initial basis $\mathcal{A}$ and final basis $\mathcal{B}$ by
$$\mathrm{Rep}_{\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}}(T)$$
The Pauli spin matrices are given by
$$\sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad$$
$$\sigma_y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad$$
$$\sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Each matrix is a representation of some linear transformation $T:\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ in some initial basis $\mathcal{A}$ and final basis $\mathcal{B}$. I don't know how ill-posed this question is, but linear maps are basis independent things, while the matrix representation does depend on the basis. I want to understand what linear map  each Pauli matrix corresponds to, and in what initial and final bases do these matrices have the matrix representation given above.

Well, the matrices are written in the eigenbasis of $\sigma_z$. I don't fully understand the question, though: The matrices fully determine the linear maps and vice versa... giving the matrix here just means to specifying how the operators act on the orthonormal eigenbasis of $\sigma_z$.

One way to think about them is that they form an irreducible representation of the Lie Algebra of SU(2), which is the double-cover of SO(3) (group of rotations in 3d). So the linear maps you are thinking about correspond to infinitesimal rotations.

@TobiasFünke this is the answer I was looking for

@Heidar I see, I'm not advanced enough to completely understand this answer, but I will come back to this as I learn more.

Indeed, in any and all bases, the eigenvalues of each Pauli matrix are $\pm 1$....
